# extract value of attribute regardless of attribute's namespace

Tags: xml, xpath, namespaces

How can I extract the value of an attribute regardless of the namespace of the attribute (and also if the attribute is in no namespace)?

E.g. what is the XPath to extract the status value attribute from **all** below documents:

```
<a status='foo'></a>

<a xmlns:x="foo-x" x:status='foo'></a>

<x:a xmlns:x="foo-x" status='foo'></x:a>

<a xmlns="foo-y" status='foo'></a>
```

The XPath `/*/@status` fetches the value 'foo' from all the above **except** the second one in which the attribute lives in a namespace (default namespaces don't apply to attributes I think so the value is successfully fetched in the fourth case). Is there an XPath I can use for all cases?

Trying `/*/@[local-name()='status']` fails with:

```
 net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: @ must be followed by a NodeTest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the `@` sign, the attribute name is expected. You can use `*` for any:

```
/*/@*[local-name()='status']
```